# Microsoft Exchange 2007: after add-MailboxPermission can the user tell?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

After running in the Exchange Shell
    add-MailboxPermission "user X" -user UserY Fullaccess

to give userY the ability to access UserX's mailbox, is there anyway that User X can tell that User Y now has full access?

Answer (score 3):

This is not detectable in Outlook, OWA or any other Exchange client, which is how all standard users usually access Exchange; however, a skilled user (or an administrator) *could* detect it by looking at the actual permissions on the AD user object or on the Exchange mailbox; this requires no actual console access to the Exchange server or to DCs, it can be accomplished with administrative tools running on any client system.

Answer (score 1):

No, unless UserY alters the content in a way that can be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

The user (user X) that has had the permissions changed on their mailbox will not know unless the mailbox is opened on another users (User Y) machine, and User Y makes changes to the contents of the mailbox.

In the past I have dealt with managers who have demanded this capability, and things got really ugly when the manager was accidentally deleting/changing items in that users mailbox.